# Build MOJO with Javafx 8

Tags: java, swing, javafx, esri, mojo

I am looking to find some example on building the Mojo application using javafx 8. I have some small application of Mojo using the swings and awt. But I am trying to replace the usage of swing and awt using Javafx.
I am confused on how to integrate the Mojo with Javafx. Any help on providing some examples should be good enough for me to further research on my application.

Below is my MOJO program using swing and awt.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import com.esri.mo2.ui.bean.Map;
import com.esri.mo2.ui.tb.ZoomPanToolBar;
import com.esri.mo2.ui.bean.Layer;
import com.esri.mo2.ui.bean.Toc;

public class QuickStart2 extends JFrame {
  Map map = new Map();
  Layer layer = new Layer();
  Layer layer2 = new Layer();
  Toc toc = new Toc();
  String s1 = "C:\\ESRI\\MOJ20\\Samples\\Data\\USA\\States.shp";
  String s2 = "C:\\ESRI\\MOJ20\\Samples\\Data\\USA\\capitals.shp";
  ZoomPanToolBar zptb = new ZoomPanToolBar();
  public QuickStart2() {
    //add a title to the window
    super("Quick Start");
    //set the size
    this.setSize(400, 300);
    //add the map to the frame
    zptb.setMap(map);
    toc.setMap(map);
    getContentPane().add(map, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(zptb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //add a shape file to the map
    addShapefileToMap(layer,s1);
    addShapefileToMap(layer2,s2);
    //add a Toc

    getContentPane().add(toc, BorderLayout.WEST);
  }
    private void addShapefileToMap(Layer layer,String s) {
    String datapath = s; //"C:\\ESRI\\MOJ20\\Samples\\Data\\USA\\States.shp";
    layer.setDataset("0;"+datapath);
    map.add(layer);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    QuickStart2 qstart = new QuickStart2();
    qstart.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Thanks, Quick Start exits");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    qstart.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Below is the output of the program.
[image]

I am running the above program using the moj_compile program.java and moj_run program .
I have the moj_compile and moj_run batch files pointed to the jdk8.